# Static (seo friendly) to dynamic url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url, dynamic-url

Here is my problem...

I have a to redirect a link like this:

> > **site.com/virtualfolder/some-seo-friendly-keywork**
> >     to
> >     **site.com/folder/page.php?id=some-seo-friendly-keyword**

In **site.com** there is no real folder "**virtualfolder**", it is virtual.
I have to take "**some-seo-friendly-keyword**" and use it as a query string

I think i have to firts match the folder "**virtualfolder**" and then capture the "**some-seo-friendly-keyword**", but how?
The **some-seo-friendly-keyword** is a string of characters and digits plus hypens so something like this below is realistic?

> > RewriteRule ^virtualfolder/([a-zA-Z0-9-])? folder/page.php?id=$1 [L]

I'm still strudying and trying mod_rewrite and it is like voodoo to me! :-/

Thank you very much for your help or your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code in htaccess:

Using the original url to show:

```
Rewriterule ^virtualfolder/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ folder/page.php?id=$1
```

Redirecting to end url using RedirectMatch (use the full URL in the second part):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/virtualfolder/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ http://www.site.com/folder/page.php?id=$1
```

Redirecting to end url using mod_rewrite (use the full URL in the second part):

```
Rewriterule ^virtualfolder/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ http://www.site.com/folder/page.php?id=$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

More info [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=301%20redirectmatch%20examples)

Comment: Hi Andrew,
no the code above do not redirect.
I think i'm missing a part in my rule...

Comment: Hi Emanuele, I edited the post to add the redirect, please try again.

Comment: Great!
Thank you very much for your help and your patience